# My very first python program! An income tax calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am brand new to python and I attempted to make a simple federal income tax calculator. There has to be a far simpler way to accomplish the same task. Here's what I created:

'''

```
# 2021 income tax calculator
print ('What\'s your yearly income after you deduct all expenses?')
myincome = int(input())
base = (myincome*.1)
e = (max(myincome-9950,0)*.02)
ex = (max(myincome-40525,0)*.1)
ext = (max(myincome-86376,0)*.02)
extr = (max(myincome-164926,0)*.08)
extra = (max(myincome-209426,0)*.03)
extras = (max(myincome-523601,0)*.02)
tax = base + e + ex + ext + extr + extra + extras
print ('You\'re gonna get screwed about~$',str(tax) + ' dollars in Federal income tax')
print ()
while True:

    print ('Try Different Income:')
    myincome = int(input())
    base = (myincome*.1)
    e = (max(myincome-9950,0)*.02)
    ex = (max(myincome-40525,0)*.1)
    ext = (max(myincome-86376,0)*.02)
    extr = (max(myincome-164926,0)*.08)
    extra = (max(myincome-209426,0)*.03)
    extras = (max(myincome-523601,0)*.02)
    tax = base + e + ex + ext + extr + extra + extras
    print ('You\'re gonna get screwed about~$',str(tax) + ' dollars in Federal income tax')
    print ()
    continue
```

'''

Comment: This is better fit for the CodeReview stack exchange.

Comment: Is there an issue?

Comment: I mean this in the kindest way, but `tax = base + e + ex + ext + extr + extra + extras` is one of the strangest things I've ever seen: it's "clever". That said, Xiddoc is referring to [codereview.se], a site to review code that works when you have _specific questions_ ([please read this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
# create a dictionary with amounts and rates (the key is the amount, the value is the rate)
stakes = {0: .1, 9950: .02, 40525: .1, 86376: .02, 164926: .08, 209426: .03, 523601: .02}

myincome = input('What\'s your yearly income after you deduct all expenses? ')

while myincome.isnumeric():  # loop ends if entered empty or non-numeric string
    myincome = int(myincome)
    # a cycle in which key-value pairs (amount-rate) are alternately extracted (unpacked)
    # from the dictionary, partial taxes is calculated and the result is summed up
    tax = sum(max(myincome - k, 0) * v for k, v in stakes.items())
    print(f'You\'re gonna get screwed about~${tax} dollars in Federal income tax')
    myincome = input('Try Different Income:')
```

Comment: You might want to explain to OP in more detail what this all does.

Comment: yes - as msandford states - this is a good idea and could be helpful for others too